# Creating Volume Mesh with GMSH using an stl file

Tags: mesh

I have a 3D stl file and I want to create a 3D mesh using this stl file.
So, in gmsh, I do as follows:

- Open the stl file
- Geometry > Elementary entities > Add > Volume
- Select the volume and press "e"
- Mesh > 3D

I always have the following error "Invalid boundary mesh segment-facet intersection) on surface 1" (see image).
Can someone help me with this error ?

A [link](https://filesender.renater.fr/?s=download&token=04d29e99-3669-4745-9cf0-8d61da1b862b) to dl the stl file.

Thank you

[Error message received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywlcd.png)

Comment: Hi Hedwin,

did you solve the issue or did you get any idea what the error is about? I am facing the same problem and would love to have some direction to solve it.

Comment: Hi @Newfarmer, I solved this problem using 3D slicer to extract the stl file and meshlab for 'only' decimation (if other tools are used, our issue came back - dont't know which tool). However, it seems that when the surface is really complex, gmsh have some issue meshing this one. 
Good luck !

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Eventualy I decided not to use gmsh. In my opinion it is too complicated (or impossible) to create a good mesh for CFD using a stl or step geometry.

Answer (score 0):

[pygalmesh](https://github.com/nschloe/pygalmesh#volume-meshes-from-surface-meshes) (a project of mine) can help you out here.